# While Exporting Inference graph for ssd lite mobilenet v2 failing due to below error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, mobilenet

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

> Key FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
>        [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at /media/drive/2f08d5f1-1439-4edf-9bb4-1d19896475a5/mobilenetV3/models-master/research/object_detection/exporter.py:341) ]]

the command I ran:

```
export_inference_graph.py- python3 export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path /home/drive/Downloads/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2019_08_14/pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix /home/drive/Downloads/raccoon_dataset-master/images/train/Chkpt/model.ckpt-20000 --output_directory /home/drive/Downloads/raccoon_dataset-master/images/exported_model_directory/clearclear
```